# Debugging of DLL plugin does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll, plugins

I'm creating a DLL file in Visual Studio 2012 which is used as a class library plugin in a proprietary program.

The program loads the plugin DLL on startup and I can access it in a visual studio like fashion in the proprietary program.

But if a method in the plugin for some reason fails, I don't always get a stack trace and I can't single step through my source files.

I have placed my PDB files in the same directory but I believe the error handling of the environment takes over so I get an error that indicates where the proprietary program failed and not where my plugin failed.

I cannot create a test stub as the DLLs are dependent on instances created in the proprietary program.

How can I, in an efficient way, debug my DLL without having to put a message/log statement on every other line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually yea, it is really easy! All you need to do is add a event for [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx). Any execption that is thrown, even if they are in a try-catch block, will get passed off to this event.

```
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    static MyPlugin()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceHandler;
    }

    static void FirstChanceHandler(object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MyErrorLogger.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: {1}",
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply that solves one of my problems, but is there a way i can single step through the code as well eg. from an external program that monitors my dll's

Comment: In visual studio go do `Debugger->Attach to process` then attach to the host process. You can then put a breakpoint in your code and it will stop and you can step though even though you have no source for the main parent application.

Comment: If your plugin in failing at the launch of the other program you can launch the program with the debugger attached. Go to the `Properties` page and the `Debugger` tab then choose the `Start External Program` option and fill in the exe for the app that uses your dll. A 2nd option is put a [Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) in your code and it will show you a window that will let you choose your Visual Studio project.

Comment: The second comment - the attach to process did the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the related .pdb file next to the .dll, that should make that information available.

Comment: Updated my question (I have placed the .pdb files in there as well).